# methodObject notation in javascript libraries (e.g. React and Sequelize)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js

In Sequelize there is a method to create a database entry with a relation to a model, for example:

```
user.createPost({...})
```

Which amounts to instance.methodInstance. I thought that the "createPost" notation was some peculiarity of Sequelize, but than I ran into React. In React you can define a component like such:

```
function Square(props) {
      return (  
        <button className="square" onClick={() => props.onClick()} >
          {props.value}
        </button>
       );
    }
```

Another component can render that like this:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square />;
  }
```

Now we have the "renderSquare" notation, which amounts to methodClass. Is this some java syntax I'm not aware of, or is it a coincidence that these two libraries have a similar style?

So I'm asking if writing a method and an object concatenated in camel case instead of the (more usual) object.method syntax is standard javascript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript​ has been evolving ridiculously quick - to a point where things can get a bit confusing.
Before ES6 there was no `class` keyword in JS. But you could achieve the same results by creating a function and attaching methods to it via the prototype.

A LOT of developers, especially the ones used to Java/C#, couldn't understand the prototype. ES6 created some syntax sugar to declare classes the old school OOP style - that's why the second example looks "java-esque". And I gotta admit - I actually love the new syntax. So much clearer.

So, that's all there is to it - you can actually use whatever approach you prefer. Just bear in mind that, with react, a component that's basically a single function (not a constructor) is supposed to be `stateless` and implement minimal logic - the kind of component that basically only renders something simple. For anything a bit more complex, you should use a stateful component - using either ES6 classes or regular ES5 with `React.createClass`.

There's a good guide here that explains most of what you need to know when it comes to ES6 vs ES5 React code:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html